# Custom plug-in to default lifecycle

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I wrote a plug-in and like it to be part of the default lifecycle.

[This article](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Attaching_the_Mojo_to_the_Build_Lifecycle) tells me i have to change the `pom.xml` of the vanilla maven project i like to execute the plug-in on. But i like to configure it in the plug-in's pom.

How to automatically execute the plug-in as part of the default lifecycle without add configuration to the build-lifecycle of the project?

Comment: You can not add a plugin to the [default life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) cause this is defined by maven itself. You always need to add an execution block...

Answer (score 1):

You can control using the phase parameter in the @Execute annotation like this

```
 @Execute(phase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE)
```

Comment: This will only define the default life cycle phase which the plugins bound to. This means you can omit the `<phase>...</phase>` in your executions configuration.